# move columns to the right if the condition is true - excel

Tags: excel

I want to search in one column cell with name Order and then select from that cell to the first empty cell and move all content to the right, is that possible?

Example is on the picture:

[image]

I tried to write this formula

```
=IF(C3 = "Order","start",IF(C3="","end",""))
```

In this way I wiill recive start and end point but i dont know how to move them to the right

Comment: Yes, it's possible.But no one here will write the code for you just because you say you want it. The condition for help here is that you tried yourself, got stuck and want advice to finish your project on your own. If you meet these criteria please publish the code you tried (as part of your modified question) and ask a question that can't be answered with yes or no.

Comment: I edited description.

Comment: It's not possible with formulae, you need VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this formula.

[C3] `=IF(LOOKUP(2,1/(ISBLANK($B$2:$B3)),ROW($B$2:$B3))<LOOKUP(2,1/($B$2:$B3="Order"),ROW($B$2:$B3)),B3,"")`

Basically, it compares the distance from the row in which it resides to the next blank cell above it in column B and the word "Order". If "Order" is nearer it copies, else it inserts a blank.

Comment: this works good, for one column, thamks!! but i want to move all columns to the right, since im having all 3 columns after column C, can i add somehow this in the formula?

Comment: Sorry, mate. This question is answered as asked and closed. If you have a new question, please describe it in a new thread.